# Understand Dankwerts boundary conditions in plug flow pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to model the advection-diffusion-reaction plug flow equation in mathematica:

$\frac{\partial C_a}{\partial t}$=$D_s$$\frac{\partial^2 C_a}{\partial z^2}-V\frac{\partial C_a}{\partial z}-kC_a$

And I have the following initial & boundary conditions:

@ t=0:  $C_a=C_{a,in}$

@ z=0:  $VC_{a,0}=VC_a|_{z=0+} -D_s \frac{\partial C_a}{\partial z}|_{z=0}$

@ z=L:  $\frac{\partial C_a}{\partial z}=0$

My question(s):

Can someone please explain to me the second boundary condition? I get that it means a constant mass flux is flowing through so I guess i'm looking for an explanation that will help me conceptualize it enough to code it?

From what I understand, the usage of this pde is invoked when you want to model a reactor that is not behaving under ideal conditions? i.e. it's conversion is between Plug Flow and CSTR?